# Layout problems in Safari on mac

Tags: html, css

in our website:
http://www.herzfit-service.de/

can tell one help me why in safari on mac
The black triangle below the logo on the left doesn’t appear, and the note on top of the people bubbles on the left is to close to the black header. Seems like it disappears behind it.

I don't have a mac but one of the workers sent me a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with Safari, it happens when you resize your browser. Just tried it on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs in any browser when it's resized to about 1366px or below. 
The header element becomes taller, which hides the triangle and div w/ the class "interview" (the people on the left). 
The easiest fix is probably to have the mobile menu appear around 1366px to avoid the menu items crowding the header bar. Or you can try media queries to set extra top margins on the elements that are disappearing.

If you are not a developer I suggest hiring one for these fixes!

Comment: _If you are not a developer I suggest hiring one for these fixes!_ I suggest refraining from thinly veiled insults in your answers. Please keep it respectful.

Comment: Hi @janfoeh thanks for your comment, it's not meant to be an insult or condescending, just trying to make a helpful suggestion in case user3401991 doesn't know how to go about making the necessary changes. user3401991 my deepest apologies if my comment offended you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following CSS style in your CSS file :style.css?ver=4.2.2

Line No:3475

```
.header-main {
         padding-right: 0;
    }
```

Remove this CSS style add check it in all browser it will work....